# Cookie Cutter from SVG

Tags: svg

I am new in Blender, decided to finally give it a go when 2.8 was released. I've only been working in Tinkercad up till now and watched a few beginners lessons on Youtube, but nowhere is there a decent tutorial on making a Cookie Cutter from a SVG file.

After I import it, I set the Geometry to Origin, use the Solidify Modifier. Change the thickness a little. From here I've been stuck. I want the model to turn into a solid (If I click Apply in Modifier) it shows me a lot of vertices when I go into edit mode. I would like to do the "offset thing inwards and make a "hole".

I am such a noob at this... can someone please help.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71137/how-to-extrude-x-and-y-axis-on-a-traced-object-flatten/71139 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92632/creating-an-bevel-inset-on-an-imported-svg/92635

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Can't wait to try this out!