# 3d printable cookie cutters

Tags: 3d-printing

I am new to blender and trying to create a cookie cutter, which I can then print using my Tevo Michelangelo printer. 
What I have tried so far - 
I created 2 svgs using Sketch as follows
[image]

Then I imported these in Blender.
Fill -  applied solidify, and set thickness as 3mm, and offset as 0. Then converted this to mesh. This will be the roof of my cutter (top part, where I can press using my hand pressure)
Stroke - Converted to mesh, selected all edges, extruded 20mm to form the wall of my cutter. Then applied solidify and set thickness as 2mm. This is how both objects look like
[image]
**Method 1** - I aligned them (using top view) and joined both objected using Command+J. This is how it looks after joining
[image]
I exported this to stl file and when I import it in CURA, it looks fine, but upon slicing, it does not print the walls.

Before Slicing - 
[image]
After Slicing(Preview mode) - 
[image]

My Print settings - 
[image]
[image]

**Method 2** - Instead of joining them using Cmd + J, I perform the boolean union operation with an overlap threshold of 0mm.

After importing in Cura, the same thing happens as above. (Same settings)

Have been struggling really hard to figure out where it went wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71137/how-to-extrude-x-and-y-axis-on-a-traced-object-flatten/71139

Comment: Thank you so much @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I was looking for something similar. Will try that approach and see if it works. Thanks.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I tried with the method you suggested. Here's another problem that I am now facing. I tried changing the shape of the section curve and fixing it, but in vain. Sharing screenshot here - https://ibb.co/Kq0gdKy

Answer (score 1):

remove the brim option in your slicer, thats why all the lines applay.
Vary the thicknes. I often had a good looking stl file and when I used the preview line by line it doenst print anything. Thats why each line/wall needs a thicknes depending on your settings.

What worked for me was the following by using an imported svg-picture(I was searching for a method to make a cookie cutter so i found your post):
Import svg
Extrude in the object data properties your curve (0.5 = 1mm) and set fill mode "none". (Now we only got the outlines)
Now convert it to a mash (right click on the object) and add the solidify modifier.
Play with the thickness and export some examples as an stl-file (you dondt need to applay the modifier before you export the stl-file - so no need to undo anything).
Load the stl-file to cura and slice it.
Check the preview if everything is printed as you like.
For e.g. I used a thickness of 0.005.