# Using svg to create a cookie cutter using regular modelling or Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, extrude, 3d-printing, svg

I'm trying to convert an imported SVG file to create a cutter (in a cube) using regular blender modelling or Geometry Nodes **(to be used as a cookie cutter after 3D printing)**.  I've looked at some of the old answers but they are outdated and the commands don't seem to be matching up.  **I'm using Blender 3.4**

**What I looked at:**

[How to extrude X and Y axis on a traced object (flatten)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71137/how-to-extrude-x-and-y-axis-on-a-traced-object-flatten/71139)

[Creating an bevel inset on an imported SVG](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92632/creating-an-bevel-inset-on-an-imported-svg/92635)

Image
[image: img1]

**I tried converting to mesh but the option doesn't show up.**

[image: img2]

[image: img3]

**I'm trying to do this in either regular modelling or Geometry Nodes so it can be 3D printed out**

See attach file below.

[image]

Comment: If you convert to Polygon Curve first (which creates a separate object) you can then convert it to regular Mesh.

Comment: Hello Rick, would it be possible to increase the line thickness of your SVG in a Vector program like Illustrator and try to convert the Curves there into a Object? 
After that you can import the new SVG and just extrude it

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by a cutter-in-a-cube? The RL cookie-cutters I'm familiar with are more or less extrusions ...

Comment: Yes one of those RL cookie cutters but 3D printable. I was going to make the imprint in a cube object for testing.

Comment: @RickT I would advise you to edit the SVG in InkScape, for example, set a line width there, turn the outlines into curves, and extrude this SVG in Blender. This way you are guaranteed to have a consistent line width without problems and artifacts.