# Cookie Cutter Rim & Bevel

Tags: svg, solidify-modifier

My wife runs a bakery & I'm regularly making custom cookie cutters for 3D printing. I'd really love to figure out how to improve my workflow to add both a rim around the top (for better stiffness) and a bevel on the bottom (to improve dough cutting). I've tried a few things, but haven't found anything quick / simple / easy / effective & would love some advice. Below is my workflow and screenshots for reference:

1. Design the cutter as an SVG in Inkscape
2. Import the SVG into Blender
3. Convert the curve to mesh
4. Enter edit mode, select all vertices
5. Extrude 12.6mm
6. Enter object mode
7. Apply the *Solidify* modifier with thickness 1.6mm, 0 offset, even thickness, Rim: Fill (exact settings vary, depending on the shape, either mode: simple or complex, etc.)
8. Export as STL

This produces a workable product for printing, but I'm looking for improvements.

Original SVG input:
[image: SVG input to workflow]

Blender Screen Shot:
[image: Blender Screen Shot]

Here's the ideal cross-section of a cutter:
[image: Ideal cutter cross section]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71137/how-to-extrude-x-and-y-axis-on-a-traced-object-flatten https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92632/creating-an-bevel-inset-on-an-imported-svg/

Comment: Hello and welcome. This question seems to have been asked before in multiple forms over time, and already has various answers but you never acknowledged any of them. We are not sure if you aware of the existing posts but none of the described techniques address your particular requisites, or you simply didn't do any research. Could you [edit] you post and clarify how your question differs from the suggested duplicates? Otherwise could you rephrase it to focus on a particular step you are stuck with?