# Curve profile overlap

Tags: extrude

I've been trying to use a curved profile along a curved path. The curve follows the path and profiles perfectly, as long as the curved path doesn't bend more than 90 degrees. Then it starts to overlap and part of the extrusion breaks through the profile.
I'm not sure I'm explaining this well!
I've tried lots of variations of problem solving, at least to the degree of my current Blender knowledge! Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.
Best to illustrate with screen shots...
[image: The problem!]
[image: The problem from another angle]
[image: The solution so far is to edit as a mesh, which can take hours. You can see in this picture the profile I'm using for the extrusion.]
[image: Hoping to achieve this, within the curved environment, without having to edit mesh!]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71137/how-to-extrude-x-and-y-axis-on-a-traced-object-flatten/